# Tor isn't fully starting nor bootstraping! Signaled readiness to systemd

Tags: linux, circuit, obfs4, bootstrapping, systemd

Tor isn't fully starting nor bootstrapping! and connections keeps on throwing time-out errors...

#### journalctl -xeu tor@default.service

```
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei systemd[29470]: tor@default.service: Executing: /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.294 [notice] Tor 0.4.7.13 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.35 as libc.
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.294 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.294 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.294 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:<hidden>
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:90605
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:<hidden>
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opened HTTP tunnel listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:<hidden>
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:<hidden>
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.296 [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:<hidden>
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Got notification message from PID 29470 (MAINPID=29470)
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /var/lib/tor/geoip.
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /var/lib/tor/geoip6.
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:56.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "bridges"
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] Bridge '<hidden>' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (<hidden>) based on the configured Bridge address.
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor '<hidden>' (cached): <hidden> [<hidden>] at <hidden> and [<hidden>]
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] Bridge '<hidden>' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (<hidden>) based on the configured Bridge address.
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor '<hidden>' (cached): <hidden> [<hidden>] at <hidden> and [<hidden>]
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:57.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Got notification message from PID 29470 (READY=1)
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Changed start -> running
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Job 23707 tor@default.service/start finished, result=done
May 13 20:34:57 ZDei systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit tor@default.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit tor@default.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 23707.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/control
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 80) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:58 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:58.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 80) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:34:59 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:34:59.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:00 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:00.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 80) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 443) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:01 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:01.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
May 13 20:35:05 ZDei tor[29470]: May 13 20:35:05.000 [notice] Your application (using socks5 to port 80) instructed Tor to take care of the DNS resolution itself if necessary. This is good.

// and alot more of useless repetitive messages
```

#### /lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=tor.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=tor.service

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
PIDFile=/run/tor/tor.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /run/tor
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutStartSec=300
TimeoutStopSec=60
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

# Hardening
AppArmorProfile=-system_tor
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectSystem=full
ReadOnlyDirectories=/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/proc
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/run
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/tor@default.service.d/override.conf

```
[Unit]
Before=shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Wants=network-pre.target nss-lookup.target ufw.service iptables.service ip6tables.service netfilter-persistent.service dhcpcd.service NetworkManager.service networkd-dispatcher.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target ufw.service iptables.service ip6tables.service netfilter-persistent.service dhcpcd.service NetworkManager.service networkd-dispatcher.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service NetworkManager-dispatcher.service

[Service]
RestartPreventExitStatus=1
RestartForceExitStatus=SIGTERM SIGILL
RestartSec=3
```

#### /etc/tor/torrc

```
SocksPort <hidden>
HTTPTunnelPort <hidden>
ControlPort <hidden>

#SocksPolicy accept 192.168.1.0/24
SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.1
SocksPolicy reject *
#####
Bridge <hidden>
Bridge <hidden>
Bridge <hidden>
Bridge <hidden>
#####
ClientOnionAuthDir /var/lib/tor/onion-auth
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
DataDirectoryGroupReadable 0
KeyDirectory /var/lib/tor/keys
KeyDirectoryGroupReadable auto
CacheDirectory /var/lib/tor/.cache
CacheDirectoryGroupReadable auto
GeoIPFile /var/lib/tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /var/lib/tor/geoip6
UseBridges 1
#CookieAuthentication 0
KeepalivePeriod 7
ProtocolWarnings 1
SafeLogging 1
Sandbox 0
ClientDNSRejectInternalAddresses 1
ClientOnly 1
ClientUseIPv4 1
ClientUseIPv6 1
ConnectionPadding auto
DownloadExtraInfo 1
EnforceDistinctSubnets 1
NewCircuitPeriod 30
MaxCircuitDirtiness 10
SafeSocks 0
TestSocks 1
LearnCircuitBuildTimeout 1
CircuitsAvailableTimeout 7
SocksTimeout 30000
DormantOnFirstStartup 1
AvoidDiskWrites 1
ClientTransportPlugin meek_lite,obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec /var/lib/tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin snowflake exec /var/lib/tor/PluggableTransports/snowflake-client -url https://snowflake-broker.torproject.net.global.prod.fastly.net/ -front cdn.sstatic.net -ice stun:stun.l.google.com:19302,stun:stun.voip.blackberry.com:3478,stun:stun.altar.com.pl:3478,stun:stun.antisip.com:3478,stun:stun.bluesip.net:3478,stun:stun.dus.net:3478,stun:stun.epygi.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.net:3478,stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478,stun:stun.uls.co.za:3478,stun:stun.voipgate.com:3478,stun:stun.voys.nl:3478
ExitPortStatistics 1
ExtraInfoStatistics 1
ExtORPort auto
Log notice stdout
#DisableNetwork 1
```

#### /lib/systemd/system/tor.service

```
# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/tor.service.d/override.conf

```
[Unit]
Before=shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Wants=network-pre.target nss-lookup.target ufw.service iptables.service ip6tables.service netfilter-persistent.service dhcpcd.service NetworkManager.service networkd-dispatcher.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target ufw.service iptables.service ip6tables.service netfilter-persistent.service dhcpcd.service NetworkManager.service networkd-dispatcher.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service NetworkManager-dispatcher.service

[Service]
StandardError=journal
StandardOutput=journal
```

Comment: Happens to me once in every few months. I do `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/tor/*; sudo systemctl restart tor`. It works fine then

Answer (score 0):

This *odd* behaviour is because of the bridges. It thinks that it has started **if** it has bootstrapped directly **or** successfully connected to the bridges specified(no matter of pluggable transports used, if any). Actually, the *real* connectivity check is needed in **both** cases - and this is just a place for another service that starts *after* Tor, uses Python and Stem library **and** resolves some dot-onion DNS names you need in a while+sleep loop, after that it exits, it's a one-shot service. And all your services that do require Tor connectivity has to be dependent on that checker service, not on Tor one, because even if you're not using bridges - you're still have a case "Host not found" even if it's 100% bootstrapped - for a first time it will not resolve it properly *in time*, but the second request will be just fine. That's why you need that tiny service